# Load Data from table into several input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, input-field

I got a Question:
How can I load data from my table into input fields?
The data in the table comes from these input fields saved in cookie.

In the table I have an image with a function, but I don't know what I should write 
in the function to get the data from a row back to the input fields where they came from.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle

Comment: i tried once... but it seems that jsfiddle doesn´t like my code.

Comment: If you like, i could send you the files. I tried jsfiddle but it doesn´t show the table.